# Computationally efficient way of maximizing a complicated multivariable function

Tags: python, math, matrix, optimization, scipy

I've been trying to find an efficient way of maximizing the following monster function in four variables but the program is taking ages to run and I'm not even sure if the results are correct. Can anyone help me code it better in Python?
Here's the function:

[image]

where

[image]

[image]

a=[p,q,r,s].

[image]

Y is the measured data sampled at 30 points.

Here's my code.

````
import numpy as np
import math

Y=Y_t    #Y_t is a predefined column vector with 30 entries.
tstep=0.05               #in s
N=30

cov=np.zeros([30,30])

def R(p,q,r,t):
    om_D=p*np.sqrt(1-q**2)
    return np.pi*r*(np.exp(-q*p*abs(t)))*(np.cos(om_D*t)+(q/(np.sqrt(1-q**2)))*(np.sin(om_D*abs(t))))/(2*q*(p**3))

def I(m,p):
    if m==p:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def func(a):   
    a1=a[0]    #natural angular frequency   bounds=[3,20]
    a2=a[1]    #damping ratio               bounds=[0,1]
    a3=a[2]    #psd of forcing signal       bounds=[300,600]
    a4=a[3]    #variance of noise           bounds=[0,0.0001] in m
    #assuming uniform prior for a, we only have to maximise the likelihood function
    
   
    for i in range(30):
        for j in range(30):
            cov[i,j]+=R(a1,a2,a3,(j-i)*tstep)+a4*I(i,j)
    P=((2*np.pi)**(-N/2)) * ((np.linalg.det(cov))**(-0.5)) * np.exp((-0.5) *np.linalg.multi_dot([np.transpose(Y),np.linalg.inv(cov),Y])) 
    return (-1)*P[0]
a_start=[5,0.05,100,0.00001]
bnds=((5,20),(0,1),(300,600),(0,0.0001))
result=spo.differential_evolution(func,bounds=bnds)
print(result.x)  ```
````

Comment: Interesting question. However, I'd recommend elaborating a bit more on the notation. Γ seems to be a covariance matrix. What is R_x[ (p-m)Δt | a] ? A conditional probability?

Comment: You might want to read up on toeplitz matrices, for that is what your covariance is, There are specially efficicnt routines for inverting and factorizing them.

Comment: Γ is the covariance matrix; |Γ| is its determinant, and R_x is the autocorrelation function.

Comment: I suggest you make this example reproducible. Second thing - do you seek another approach (better optimization algorithm) or you just want speed your code, better performance?

Comment: @dankal444 If there's a better optimization algorithm, I'd be grateful if you could share it. This program is taking half an hour to run with just 30 data points. I have to increase the data points and the number of variables in future practice. So, it shouldn't cause me trouble.

Comment: @ShakirRather could you supply some values in Y_t and the result, I want to run some experiments and check if it can match your result.

Comment: @ferdy Take Y_t=[[-0.00445551]
 [-0.01164452]
 [-0.02171495]
 [-0.03475491]
 [-0.00770873]
 [ 0.0492236 ]
 [ 0.07264838]
 [ 0.03066707]
 [-0.02457141]
 [-0.04065968]
 [-0.01135125]
 [ 0.02677074]
 [ 0.06517749]
 [ 0.09611112]
 [ 0.12300657]
 [ 0.0923581 ]
 [ 0.03982604]
 [-0.01473844]
 [-0.09024497]
 [-0.14304097]
 [-0.17447606]
 [-0.16926952]
 [-0.12006193]
 [-0.00120763]
 [ 0.11006087]
 [ 0.19978283]
 [ 0.24388584]
 [ 0.18768875]
 [ 0.12844553]
 [ 0.03099409]]

Comment: Got `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars` in `return np.pi*r*(np.exp(-q*p*abs(t))) ...` after 30k calls to func(). This is using 2 cores. But with single core, it works fine with result `[1.03680424e+01 3.48922881e-01 4.88629404e+02 7.33408631e-05]` after 16 minutes on my pc.

Comment: In R() the expression `...(np.sin(om_D*abs(t))))/(2*q*(p**3)` is not right when q is zero, so a2 should have a minimum value of more than 0.

Comment: @ferdy The fact that it's taking so long is precisely why I'm bothered. My actual task is to consider more than 500 data points and do this optimization. I'm afraid that may not be possible. And q is definitely more than zero and less than 1

Comment: Can you replicate my answer for the differential_evolution only of course.

Comment: @ferdy Sure. Could you share the scipy.optimize.minimize code with me?

Comment: @ShakirRather, minimize() code is added see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in cov initialization that is why it does not converge. Also an issue on bound for damping ratio, was `(0, 1)` now `(0.0001, 0.999)` the ratio should not be 0 or 1 because if it is there will be division by zero error in `R()`. Code is fixed now see also the output.

##### Code

```
import time

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution


Y = [[-0.00445551], [-0.01164452], [-0.02171495], [-0.03475491], [-0.00770873], [ 0.0492236 ],
[ 0.07264838], [ 0.03066707], [-0.02457141], [-0.04065968], [-0.01135125], [ 0.02677074], [ 0.06517749],
[ 0.09611112], [ 0.12300657], [ 0.0923581 ], [ 0.03982604], [-0.01473844], [-0.09024497], [-0.14304097],
[-0.17447606], [-0.16926952], [-0.12006193], [-0.00120763], [ 0.11006087], [ 0.19978283], [ 0.24388584],
[ 0.18768875], [ 0.12844553], [ 0.03099409]]    #Y_t is a predefined column vector with 30 entries.
tstep = 0.05               #in s
N = 30


def R(p,q,r,t):
    om_D = p*np.sqrt(1-q**2)
    return np.pi*r*(np.exp(-q*p*abs(t)))*(np.cos(om_D*t)+(q/(np.sqrt(1-q**2)))*(np.sin(om_D*abs(t))))/(2*q*(p**3))


def I(m,p):
    if m==p:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def func(a):
    cov=np.zeros([N,N])

    a1=a[0]    #natural angular frequency   bounds=[3,20]
    a2=a[1]    #damping ratio               bounds=[0,1]
    a3=a[2]    #psd of forcing signal       bounds=[300,600]
    a4=a[3]    #variance of noise           bounds=[0,0.0001] in m
    #assuming uniform prior for a, we only have to maximise the likelihood function
   
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            cov[i,j]+=R(a1,a2,a3,(j-i)*tstep)+a4*I(i,j)
    P=((2*np.pi)**(-N/2)) * ((np.linalg.det(cov))**(-0.5)) * np.exp((-0.5) *np.linalg.multi_dot([np.transpose(Y),np.linalg.inv(cov),Y])) 
    return (-1)*P[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t0 = time.perf_counter()

    a_start = [5, 0.05, 350, 0.00001]
    bnds = ((5, 20), (0.0001, 0.999), (300, 600), (0, 0.0001))

    result=differential_evolution(func, x0=a_start, bounds=bnds, maxiter=1000)
    print(result)

    print(f'elapse: {time.perf_counter() - t0:0.0f}s')
```

##### Output

```
     fun: array([-2.76736878e+11])
     jac: array([-2.91459845e+11, -4.55652161e+12,  1.27377279e+10,  3.34234132e+14])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 3430
     nit: 56
 success: True
       x: array([ 20.   ,   0.999, 300.   ,   0.   ])
elapse: 55s
```

##### Scipy minimize is very fast

Changes:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

result = minimize(func, x0=a_start, bounds=bnds, options={'maxiter': 100, 'disp': True})
```

Output:

```
      fun: array([-2.76736878e+11])
 hess_inv: <4x4 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([-2.91459845e+11, -4.55652161e+12,  1.27377279e+10,  3.34234132e+14])
  message: 'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'
     nfev: 30
      nit: 4
     njev: 6
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 20.   ,   0.999, 300.   ,   0.   ])
elapse: 0.5s
```

##### Optuna

[Optuna](https://github.com/optuna/optuna) after 1000 trials is right there too.
value is positive here because I use maximize direction. In both scipy's DE and minimize values have to be negated.

```
best param: {'a1': 20, 'a2': 0.9989999999999999, 'a3': 300, 'a4': 0.0}
best value: 276736878140.3103
best trial num: 73
elapse: 22s
```